# Error as a single value to represent a set of data

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, descriptive-statistics

Let's say I have a set of data which consist of Real Value, Approximation I, Approximation II. For instance, the data looks like this:

[image: Data Sample]

Now, I'm not sure which error to choose so one can infer that Approx. II is better than Approx. I. What I did so far is calculate the relative error for each points (which is a lot), then say that

> $\dots$ by observation, we could see that approx. II gives lower relative error than approx. I $\dots$

The thing is, while the majority is true, at some points, approx. II gives higher relative error. So I couldn't say that the statement is entirely true.

Are there any error, as a single value, that could represent this kind of data? I've been looking at SSE (Sum Squared Error), but I'm not sure it's what I need...

Any insight would really help, thanks beforehand.

Comment: You can calculate the standard deviation for both approximations: $s=\sqrt{\frac1n\cdot \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(x_i^A-x_i^R\right)^2}$, where $x_i^R$ is data i of the real values and $x_i^A$ the data i of the approximated values. The lower the standard deviation, the better is the approximation.

Comment: The average deviation should be calculated first: $\frac1n\cdot \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(x_i^A-x_i^R\right)$. If they do not differ to much, then you go on and calculate the standard deviations like above.